# How to find the pulled date of an image in Harbor with skopeo inspect?

Tags: harbor, skopeo

How to get the docker image when has been pulled with skopeo inspect?

When I use skopeo inspect --tls-verify=false docker://${image_path}:${tag} --config
I can only find the key value "created" without "pulled".
If skopeo is not OK, curl should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

The pulled date is not part of the spec. The pull date is only in Harbor and skopeo is only spec compliant. Using curl, harbor-cli or api client will do it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Finally I use curl to do it. The script is in below:

#get the image_artifacts and change to url format
Image_artifacts=$(printf ${Image#*/}|jq -sRr '@uri'|sed 's|%2F|%252F|g')
curl -u $Harbor_User:$Harbor_Passwd -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET "http://${Harbor_Address}/api/v2.0/projects/$Project/repositories/${Image_artifacts}/artifacts?page_size=100"|jq '.[]|select (.pull_time>"2023-02-06")'|jq '.tags[].name'

Comment: You should answer your own question. It’s better then just commenting on mine